# Create IntelliJ IDEA plugin that submit a form

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm learning about how to create an IntelliJ plugin. I was reading through some of the documentation on JetBrains. With that documentation, I've created a sample project and now I understand little bits and pieces of SDK. What I'm struggling with right now is how can I create a form that takes some input from the user, submit the form and show the response that it got from the server.

This can be under the tools window. Any sample GitHub project that does something like this?

Answer (score 0):

in `plugin.xml` you should add

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
...
<toolWindow factoryClass="SomeClass" id="someUniqueID" />
</extensions>
```

and then create the factory class like this

```
public class SomeClass implements ToolWindowFactory {
  @Override
  public void createToolWindowContent(@NotNull Project p, @NotNull ToolWindow w) {
    ContentFactory contentFactory = ContentFactory.SERVICE.getInstance();
    JComponent form = new MyMagicForm(...);
    Content content = contentFactory.createContent(form, "My form", false);
    content.setCloseable(false);      
    w.getComponent().putClientProperty(ToolWindowContentUi.HIDE_ID_LABEL, "true");
    w.getContentManager().addContent(content);
  }
}
```